# How do I import a SQL dump into pgadmin 4 using postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, bash, pgadmin-4

I have a SQL dump that I need to import using postgresql into pgadmin4, however when I run the command, the schema gets created but none of the data comes with it, I have the database set up in pgadmin4. This is my first time using postgresql and pgadmin so I know I have to be missing something.
The SQL dump file was sent to me directly, I did not use pg_dump to migrate anything, the file is in my downloads and I need to plug it in to pgadmin.

I need this SQL dump because I need to log into several portals locally for a large project.

On Windows, using postgres version 14, I've tried several ways from other solutions on stack overflow, first using the command line in both bash and powershell
This here is the command I was told to use that should add the tables and data for the app from a coworker, and it worked fine for him.

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin>psql -h localhost -U postgres -d the_database -f PATH_TO_YOUR_DOWNLOADS\data_dump.sql
```

This command will create the schema in the pgadmin database but no data comes with it. (I know the data is missing because I cant use my dummy logins to get into the project)

Second, I tried using the built in restore and backup methods in pgadmin and both of those end in an error

> `Process failed Restoring backup on the server 'PostgreSQL 14 (localhost:5432)

Third I tried using the query tool and link the sql file that way, but when I hit execute I get an error there as well.
Using the query tool, when I link the download file, I can see the data in the Query, but it is not in the database.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2"
LINE 3285: 2 Some Test 2020-11-13 07:42:29.356827 2020-11-13 04:32:...
           ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 87447
```

Any advice?

Do I need the SQL file formatted in any certain way?
I just need the data to be imported into pgadmin4 database WITH my schema.

Comment: "Syntax error" sounds exactly like that. Without more details about the dump, it's impossible to provide help, especially as this is not related to programming

Comment: pgAdmin's query tool can not run the SQL script generated by pg_dump because it does not support the way `copy` is used in the script. If you want to run the script with any SQL tool other than `psql` you need to run `pg_dump` with the `--inserts` option.

Comment: @NicoHaase What other info do you need about the the dump?

Comment: **To your question add**: 1) What version of Postgres did you dump from? 2) What was the complete dump command? 3) Have you down `pg_dumapall -g` on the old server to get the global objects e.g. the users/roles? And did you restore that to the new server? 4) After doing `psql -h localhost -U postgres -d the_database -f PATH_TO_YOUR_DOWNLOADS\data_dump.sql` can you do `psql -h localhost -U postgres -d the_database` and login and see if the tables and data is there?